# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Tags: python-imaging-library

I have the same problem as was asked by trevor however the answers don't assist me at all.

I'm on Window 10, running Pyscriper 3.6.3.0 and Python 3.8.2 in 32 bit.

I've searched the Pillow site and those instruction just result in a different error where pip is invalid syntax. The biggest issue I'm finding is that there is way too much out of date on Google and the forums.

I was of the belief that Pillow already came with 3.8.2?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root = Tk()
root.title('TimeLord Frames')
root.iconbitmap('TBA')  # Still need to work on icon.

frame = LabelFrame(root, text="This is my Frame.., padx=5, pady=5")
frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

b = Button(frame, text="Click Here")
b.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I have found the problem. It comes from the  line:
root.iconbitmap('TBA')  # Still need to work on icon.

Because I haven't resolved an issue with the icon, it is looking at "from PIL import ImageTk,Image" and not connecting the 2 together. I have tried inserting the location of my icon, but it's not happy with that either. If I # out bothe line refering to images, I can get the program to run.

Cheers